# Open up memes from a .jpg file when the pc starts up using Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to open files in a directory that doesn't have just .jpg files in it
here's the code i wrote:

```
import os
import random
import time, shutil
path=(r"C:\Users\KIMEDIAS\Desktop\Noice\PYTHON")
files=os.listdir(path)
d = random.choice(files)
os.startfile(d)
time.sleep(2)
quit()
```

Can someone help me so i can specify the file type it open's. And, if you can make it close the process and delete the file after some seconds.

Comment: Hint: Use https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html and you'll be able to do it easier. Try loops and get files that match an specific suffix ;)

Comment: but how can i use it,can you give an example pls

Answer (score 0):

You can use glob to get a certain type of files

```
import glob

path=(r"C:\Users\KIMEDIAS\Desktop\Noice\PYTHON\*.jpg")
files=glob.glob(path)
print(files)
```

Comment: TY so much,youre a life saver :)

Answer (score 0):

Please see this question which should supply the answer your looking for: [Find all files in a directory with extension .txt in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)